# how to generate horizontal line in pdfkit as per content length exceed

Tags: node.js, express, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

```
const { createInvoice } = require("./createInvoice.js");

const invoice = {
  shipping: {
    name: "John Doe",
    address: "1234 Main Street",
    city: "San Francisco",
    state: "CA",
    country: "US",
    postal_code: 94111
  },
  items: [
    {
      item: "TC 100",
      description: "The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy little dog. The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy little dog. The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy little dog.",
      quantity: 2,
      amount: 6000
    },
    {
      item: "USB_EXT",
      description: "USB Cable Extender",
      quantity: 1,
      amount: 2000
    }
  ],
  subtotal: 8000,
  paid: 0,
  invoice_nr: 1234
};

createInvoice(invoice, "invoice.pdf");
```

Invoice.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");

function createInvoice(invoice, path) {
  console.log(incoice)
  let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });

  generateHeader(doc);
  generateCustomerInformation(doc, invoice);
  generateInvoiceTable(doc, invoice);
  generateFooter(doc);

  doc.end();
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
}

function generateHeader(doc) {
  doc
    .image("logo.png", 50, 45, { width: 50 })
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(20)
    .text("ACME Inc.", 110, 57)
    .fontSize(10)
    .text("ACME Inc.", 200, 50, { align: "right" })
    .text("123 Main Street", 200, 65, { align: "right" })
    .text("New York, NY, 10025", 200, 80, { align: "right" })
    .moveDown();
}

function generateCustomerInformation(doc, invoice) {
  doc
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(20)
    .text("Invoice", 50, 160);

  generateHr(doc, 185);

  const customerInformationTop = 200;

  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .text("Invoice Number:", 50, customerInformationTop)
    .font("Helvetica-Bold")
    .text(invoice.invoice_nr, 150, customerInformationTop)
    .font("Helvetica")
    .text("Invoice Date:", 50, customerInformationTop + 15)
    .text(formatDate(new Date()), 150, customerInformationTop + 15)
    .text("Balance Due:", 50, customerInformationTop + 30)
    .text(
      formatCurrency(invoice.subtotal - invoice.paid),
      150,
      customerInformationTop + 30
    )

    .font("Helvetica-Bold")
    .text(invoice.shipping.name, 300, customerInformationTop)
    .font("Helvetica")
    .text(invoice.shipping.address, 300, customerInformationTop + 15)
    .text(
      invoice.shipping.city +
        ", " +
        invoice.shipping.state +
        ", " +
        invoice.shipping.country,
      300,
      customerInformationTop + 30
    )
    .moveDown();

  generateHr(doc, 252);
}

function generateInvoiceTable(doc, invoice) {
  let i;
  const invoiceTableTop = 330;

  doc.font("Helvetica-Bold");
  generateTableRow(
    doc,
    invoiceTableTop,
    "Item",
    "Description",
    "Unit Cost",
    "Quantity",
    "Line Total"
  );
  generateHr(doc, invoiceTableTop + 20);
  doc.font("Helvetica");

  for (i = 0; i < invoice.items.length; i++) {
    const item = invoice.items[i];
    const position = invoiceTableTop + (i + 1) * 30;
    generateTableRow(
      doc,
      position,
      item.item,
      item.description,
      formatCurrency(item.amount / item.quantity),
      item.quantity,
      formatCurrency(item.amount)
    );

    generateHr(doc, position + 20);
  }

  const subtotalPosition = invoiceTableTop + (i + 1) * 30;
  generateTableRow(
    doc,
    subtotalPosition,
    "",
    "",
    "Subtotal",
    "",
    formatCurrency(invoice.subtotal)
  );

  const paidToDatePosition = subtotalPosition + 20;
  generateTableRow(
    doc,
    paidToDatePosition,
    "",
    "",
    "Paid To Date",
    "",
    formatCurrency(invoice.paid)
  );

  const duePosition = paidToDatePosition + 25;
  doc.font("Helvetica-Bold");
  generateTableRow(
    doc,
    duePosition,
    "",
    "",
    "Balance Due",
    "",
    formatCurrency(invoice.subtotal - invoice.paid)
  );
  doc.font("Helvetica");
}

function generateFooter(doc) {
  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .text(
      "Payment is due within 15 days. Thank you for your business.",
      50,
      780,
      { align: "center", width: 500 }
    );
}

function generateTableRow(
  doc,
  y,
  item,
  description,
  unitCost,
  quantity,
  lineTotal
) {
  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .text(item, 50, y)
    .text(description, 150, y)
    .text(unitCost, 280, y, { width: 90, align: "right" })
    .text(quantity, 370, y, { width: 90, align: "right" })
    .text(lineTotal, 0, y, { align: "right" });
}

function generateHr(doc, y) {
  doc
    .strokeColor("#aaaaaa")
    .lineWidth(1)
    .moveTo(50, y)
    .lineTo(550, y)
    .stroke();
}

function formatCurrency(cents) {
  return "$" + (cents / 100).toFixed(2);
}

function formatDate(date) {
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  return year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
}

module.exports = {
  createInvoice
};
```

The height and width is not adjustable in pdfkit. If I added long text into description under items its messed up the content into lines.

What I expect it should be dynamically generatehr based on content rather than fixed. how this is possible please guide on it.

Also it should work on address if address text become larger it should be adjustable.

Any help ?

Thanks